# Side Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, popup

I was interested in putting a popup window that appeared on the bottom-left side of the page, kind of like the [Cloudflare Flashcard](https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/flashcard) app, but in pure JS and HTML.

It would look somewhat [like this](https://images.cloudflareapps.com/UaFLKyr4SFS65MuxmcO0_Graphic%20-%203.png), on the bottom left of the page, but it would not interfere with the scrolling or be a modal.

Thanks,
Coding

Comment: This site is recognized to solve problems or challenges, not to solve your task. give some of the code you have tried and ask for help, not ask to make whole code for me

Comment: Have my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the window you could use this css:

```
.popup {
   position: fixed;
   left: 20px;
   bottom: 20px;
}
```

And to show/hide:

```
document.querySelector(".popup").style.opacity = 1; // show
document.querySelector(".popup").style.opacity = 0; // hide
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/wq12aju5/